# Is there a quick way to switch between iTunes accounts in AppleTV?

Tags: itunes, appletv

Is there a quick way to switch between iTunes accounts in AppleTV?

The Apple TV Software Update 5.1 supposedly supports 'Save[ing] multiple iTunes accounts and switch quickly between them.'

You can save multiple accounts, but going into settings doesn't seem to be a quick way to switch?
the KB lists the feature ( http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4448 )- but I can't find any other mentions?

Comment: I was sort of hoping for an icon on the home screen.

Comment: Nothing. Really?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to switch is via the account settings.

Comment: I frequently use several accounts this way. We have about four in our family. One is for an account for my home country. It's great because I can use it to purchase and show movies in my original language to my kid for educational purpose. This can't be done on iPad or computers because iTunes punishes you after changing account by not being able to change to another account for months. Never understood the reason for that.